# Forms error - __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix'

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 forms in one  and i added prefix to separate it in view. But I get error: **__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix'**

I read documentation about prefix and other issue on stack about it but this doesn't help me.

**My view.py:**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
def client_create(request):
    dict = {}
    dict['title'] = 'New client'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_user = ClientUserCreateForm(request.POST, prefix="test1")
        form_client = ClientCreateForm(request.POST, prefix="test2")
        return HttpResponse(request.POST['first_name'])
        # if form_user.is_valid() and form_client.is_valid():
        #     print(request.POST)
    else:
        dict['form_user'] = ClientUserCreateForm(prefix="test1")
        dict['form_client'] = ClientCreateForm(prefix="test2")
        return render(request, 'panel/client/create.html', dict)
```

I have two forms and they have init and when i remove it from form then prefix work's correct.

**My forms.py**

```
class ClientUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def __init__(self):
        super(ClientUserCreateForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-text',
        })
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-text',
        })
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-text',
        })


class ClientCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.Select(
        choices=CountriesShortcut.objects.all().values_list('code', 'name').order_by('id')
    ))
    forwarding_country = forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.Select(
        choices=CountriesShortcut.objects.all().values_list('code', 'name').order_by('id')
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('name', 'vat', 'address', 'zip_code', 'city', 'country', 'forwarding_address',
                  'forwarding_zip_code', 'forwarding_city', 'forwarding_country', 'phone',
                  'mailing_email', 'regon')

    def __init__(self):
       super(ClientCreateForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-text',
        })
        self.fields['vat'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-text',
        })
        (....)
        self.fields['regon'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-text',
        })
```

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/panel/client/create/

Django Version: 1.8.8
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'client',
 'registration',
 'avatar',
 'filer',
 'mptt',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'reversion',
'guardian')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\loc\PycharmProjects\CRM\core\views.py" in client_create
  72.         dict['form_user'] = ClientUserCreateForm(prefix="test1")

Exception Type: TypeError at /panel/client/create/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix'
```

**Traceback 2 - after update __init__:**

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/panel/client/create/

Django Version: 1.8.8
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'client',
 'registration',
 'avatar',
 'filer',
 'mptt',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'reversion',
 'guardian')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\loc\PycharmProjects\CRM\core\views.py" in client_create
  73.         dict['form_client'] = ClientCreateForm(prefix="test2")
File "C:\Users\loc\PycharmProjects\CRM\core\forms.py" in __init__
  75.         super(ClientUserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /panel/client/create/
Exception Value: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're overriding the form's `__init__` method, and you're not accepting any arguments in the new method. It's the easiest to just accept and pass all arguments:

```
ClientUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientUserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type from line:  dict['form_client'] = ClientCreateForm(prefix="test2") - i need add data attribute now?

Comment: For the second traceback: In the `ClientCreateForm`, you must call `super` with `ClientCreateForm`. You have `super(ClientUserCreateForm, self)`.